# Kendo UI grid datetime column

Tags: grid, filtering, kendo-ui

I would like to have a `DateTime` column in my Kendo UI grid. I've searched on forums, but I didn't find a solution for this problem.

My field for the TimeStamp column is defined such as:

```
TimeStamp: { type: "date" },
```

The records are showing data according to the format specified in the template. But I would like to be able to filter my data source with greater precision. However, currently my filter is only able to filter by date. Is there a way to filter by `DateTime` instead of filtering only by date?

Comment: You currently can't use date and time - only date. The format of the column does not propagate to the date picker in the filter menu.

Comment: I was absolutely sure that this is the case, but thank you for the confirmation. Can you tell me whether the implementation of this feature is planned into a future version? I understand that this is not supported currently, but will Kendo UI support more precize datetime filters? Should I put this idea into the forum? Also, if you edit your answer to contain the information that DateTime filters are currently not supported in Kendo UI, I will upvote and accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was informed that this is not possible currently with Kendo UI. I know this is bad news, but this is the answer to my question.

Comment: Wow, that sucks. A lot. I just migrated a web service and set up a json endpoint specifically to use the KendoUI grid, and now I have to return preformatted DateTimes as strings. Not the biggest problem in the world, but frustrating all the same.

Comment: @millie, that was a year ago. Maybe they have solved the problem since then.

Comment: My comment was only about one and a half months after the answer, but the problem has been fixed. The only problem is that the default date and time pickers are activated by two separate buttons that look like one. That could be easily fixed though. http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it to use template on kendo grid column, create one more property and pass that property in template in kendo grid column.

like

```
timeStamp: { type: "date" },
timeStamp1: { type: "String" },
```

pass timestamp1 in template like

```
  {
    title: "Last Login",
    width: 80,
    template: '<span>#= timeStamp1#</span>',
    field: "timeStamp",
    type: "date"                               
  },
```

its work fine according your requirement and sorting will work fine like database sorting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this dodges the issue. Filtering datetimes as strings does NOT give correct results in most cases and this also increases your http request sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Its Posible:

```
DeliveredDate: {
                type: "datetime",
                editable: false,
                nullable: false
            }
```

And the template is:

```
            {
                field: "DeliveredDate",
                title: "Delivered Date",
                template: '#= kendo.toString(data.DeliveredDate,"dd/MM/yyyy") === null ? "--/--/----" : kendo.toString(data.DeliveredDate,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") + " Hrs" #',
                width: 60,
                groupable: false,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest Way to us the TimeStamp format data from your Database for KendoGrid.

In your HTML file, use the data from DB as shown.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData"> 
    <kendo-grid-column class="CreatedAt" field="CreatedAt" title="title"
     [width]="120" [headerStyle]="{'background-color': '#36455a','color': '#fff'}"
     [style]="{'background-color': '#36455a','color': '#fff'}">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
             {{dataItem.CreatedAt | date:"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"}}
          </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

PS: gridData is my var that stores Data from DB. and CreatedAt is one of the fields.