# What is the proper way to format a UNIX timestamp into a human date in Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: date, kendo-ui, timestamp, kendo-grid, unix-timestamp

Well there seems to be a multitude of similar questions, but none that I can find answering this specific question.. so here goes..

Have a working Kendo UI grid.  My datasource is returning a timestamp - here's the JSON response coming back to the code:

[image]

You'll notice that the next line is also a date.. returned by MySQL as a standard DateTime format - which I would be happy to use directly.  But I've converted the date to a timestamp which I thought would be more universal.  (??)

Now I need to do two things - format the timestamp into a readable date and edit the date so it can be saved back to the datasource.  But let's tackle formatting first.

My code to display the column currently looks like this:

```
    {   title: "Trial<br>Date", 
    field: "customer_master_converted_to_customer_date",
    format: "{0:d/M/yyyy}",
    attributes: {
        style: "text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"
    },
    filterable: true,
    headerAttributes: {
        style: "font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;"
    }
},
```

Although I've tried..

```
    toString(customer_master_converted_to_customer_date, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

.. and several variations of that - in terms of format string.  And yes, I've tried entering:

```
    type: "date",
```

No matter what I do, I only get the timestamp.

[image]

Anyone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kendo UI grid datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861998/kendo-ui-grid-datetime-column)

Answer (score 4):

You need to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript) the timestamp to a JavaScript date first. Here is a sample implementation:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { date: 1371848019 }
    ],
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          date: {
            type: "date",
            parse: function(value) {
              return new Date(value * 1000);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is it live: http://jsbin.com/utonil/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the response Atanas.  However, isn't this supposed to accomplish the same thing.. assuming that you don't convert the date to a unix timestamp?

`title: "Trial<br>Date", 
        field: "customer_master_converted_to_customer_date",
        type: "date",
        template: " #= kendo.toString(customer_master_converted_to_customer_date, 'M/d/yyyy') # ",
        attributes: {
         style: "text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"
        },
        filterable: true,
        headerAttributes: {
         style: "font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;"`
        }

Comment: No, you cannot format a number to a date. You need to parse it first.

Comment: What about if the returned item was not a unix timestamp, but a date.. like I show in the example just below the timestamp?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry.. should have been more specific.  So if you look at the original question - I have a graphic pointing to the timestamp.  Right under that is a regular date value being returned.. I mention it in the question.  So my comment was asking if the same holds true for a regular date item (and in Kendo it's specified as a date).  Shouldn't you be able to format a date item (specified as date item)?  That doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You should specify in the model configuration that the field is a date. Here is how: http://jsbin.com/utonil/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and i tried this and now works perfectly, good luck.

```
template :#= kendo.toString(new Date(parseInt(dateOfBirth)), 'yyyy-MM-dd')#"
```

whre dateOfBirth is the date to format, the result will be like this : 2015-09-11.
good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Atanas Korchev, that worked for me, here is what I ended up doing:

```js
// in datasource
    schema:{
      model: {
        fields: {
          date: { type: "date",
                    parse: function(value) {
                      return new Date(value);
                    }
          }, // … other fields

    // in columns
    columns: [
        {
          field: "date",
          title: "Date",
          type: "date",
          format: "{0:dd MMM yyyy}"
        },
        // ... other columns
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use the TimeStamp format data from your database for KendoGrid.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67106362/5671943

```
<kendo-grid-column class="CreatedAt" field="CreatedAt" title="title"
 [width]="120" [headerStyle]="{'background-color': '#36455a','color': '#fff'}"
 [style]="{'background-color': '#36455a','color': '#fff'}">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
         {{dataItem.CreatedAt | date:"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"}}
      </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```